# Class loading issue with Eclipse RAP and WebLogic 12.2.1.3

Tags: weblogic12c, eclipse-rap

Whilst deploying an Eclipse RAP war file on WebLogic 12.2.1.3, we are encountering the following error;

***java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/aopalliance/aop/Advice"***

After performing some analysis we identified the issue is due to WebLogic 12.2.1.3 shipping with org.glassfish.hk2.external.aopalliance-repackaged.jar within oracle_common\modules, and this conflicts with com.springsource.org.aopalliance_1.0.0.jar, within the WEB-INF\plugins directory of our WAR file.

We have tried a few things to remediate this, but with no luck so far;

Removed org.glassfish.hk2.external.aopalliance-repackaged.jar from oracle_common\modules (WebLogic deploys but then shuts itself down)

Remove com.springsource.org.aopalliance_1.0.0.jar from the WAR file (WebLogic starts, but does not deploy the bundles within the WAR file)

Updated weblogic.xml in the WAR file with;

```
<container-descriptor>
  <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  <prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.aopalliance.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

Copied com.springsource.org.aopalliance_1.0.0.jar to the WEB-INF\lib folder of the WAR, with the above weblogic.xml change

Any suggestions of other changes we could try would be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try updating the launch.ini in your war file, setting the values for osgi.parentClassloader and osgi.contextClassLoaderParent to ext :-

```
osgi.parentClassloader=ext
osgi.contextClassLoaderParent=ext
```

Cheers

Rod

Comment: thanks Rod, that seems to have fixed it! Much appreciated!